# Strange behavior of LENGTH command - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I've encountered here an inusited situation that I couldn't understand. Nor the documentation of the functions that I will write about has something to light up this thing.

I've a table with a field `titulo varchar2(55)`. I'm in Brazil, some of the characters in this field has accents and my goal is to create a similar field without the accents (replaced by the original character as this `á` became `a` and so on.).

I could use a bunch of functions to do that as `replace`, `translate` and others but I find over the internet one that seams to be more elegant, then I use it. That is where the problem came.

My update code is like:

```
update myTable 
   set TITULO_URL = replace(
                 utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
                           nlssort(titulo, 'nls_sort=binary_ai')
                                         )
                            ,' ','_');
```

As I said the goal is to transform every accented character in its equivalent without the accent plus the spaces character for an `_`

Then I got this error:

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column 
     "mySchem"."myTable"."TITULO_URL" (actual: 56, maximum: 55)
```

And at first I though maybe those functions are adding some character, let me checkit. I did a select command to get me a row where `titulo` has 55 characters.

```
select titulo from myTable where length(titulo) = 55
```

Then I choose a row to do some tests, the row that I choose has this value: `'FGHJTÓRYO DE YHJKS DA DGHQÇÃA DE ASGA XCVBGL EASDEÔNASD'` (I did change it bit to preserve the data, but the result is the same)

When i do the following select statement that things became weird:

```
select a, length(a), b, length(b)
  from ( select 'FGHJTÓRYO DE YHJKS DA DGHQÇÃA DE ASGA XCVBGL EASDEÔNASD' a,
                replace(
                   utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( 
                               nlssort('FGHJTÓRYO DE YHJKS DA DGHQÇÃA DE ASGA XCVBGL EASDEÔNASD', 'nls_sort=binary_ai')
                                           )
                       ,' ','_') b
           from dual
       )
```

The result for this sql is (i will put the values one down other for better visualization):

```
                     a                                       LENGTH(a)
FGHJTÓRYO DE YHJKS DA DGHQÇÃA DE ASGA XCVBGL EASDEÔNASD        55     
                     b                                       LENGTH(b)
fghjtoryo_de_yhjks_da_dghqcaa_de_asga_xcvbgl_easdeonasd        56
```

Comparing the two strings one above other there is no difference in size:

```
FGHJTÓRYO DE YHJKS DA DGHQÇÃA DE ASGA XCVBGL EASDEÔNASD
fghjtoryo_de_yhjks_da_dghqcaa_de_asga_xcvbgl_easdeonasd
```

I've tested this query on Toad, PLSQL Developer and SQLPLUSW all with the same result. So my question is **Where this LENGTH(b)=56 came from**? I know that it can be something with character set, but I couldn't figure out why. I even tested with the `trim` command and the result is the same.

Another tests that i did

- `substr(b, 1,55)` the result was the same text as above
- `lenght(trim(b))` the result was 56
- `substr(b,56)` the result was empty (no null, no space, just empty)

Suggested by @Sebas:

- `LENGTHB(b)` the result was 56
- `ASCII(substr(b,56))`

So, again: **Where this LENGTH(b)=56 came from**?

Sorry for the long post and thank you for the ones who get down here (read everything).
An thanks for the ones who doesn't read anyway :)

Best regards

Comment: what does `LENGTHB(b)` says?

Comment: @Sebas LENGTHB(b) = 56 I will edit my post adding this info.

Comment: `SELECT ASCII(substr(b,56)) FROM DUAL;` ?

Comment: [Do you see](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/20180) zero terminator in column B (`nlssort` result)?

Comment: @Sebas ASCII(substr(b,56)) = 0 I will edit again with this test also.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff the result for the query that you post at fiddle was `6667686A746F72796F2064652079686A6B73206461206467687163616120646520617367612078637662676C2065617364656F6E61736400` tested on Toad and sqlplusw

Comment: I think we got the problem, @EgorSkriptunoff's suggestion and the ASCII result show that there is a NULL character (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) added by `NLSSORT`.

Comment: So is there a **why** it is doing this? I did find this post as bit relative on asktom: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7143933880166#144422600346503784 the end of the post suggest a bug.

Comment: Probably, it is usual behavior of NLSSORT - to terminate strings with chr(0).

Comment: you can trim off the null: length(rtrim(b, chr(0)))

Comment: @tbone In order to solve my problem I already did that: `set TITULO_URL = substr(replace(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(titulo, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))),' ','_'),1,55);` before I post the question :)

Comment: As @EgorSkriptunoff said, the nlssort is adding the NULL, so thats your answer for the "why" the lengths are different (and easy enough to trim off).  If you are asking why does nlssort add the null terminator in the first place, not sure, but it may be a carry-over from C code, where null terminating strings is common (again, purely a guess)

Comment: @tbone Yeah, I'm familiarized with C programming and knew the Null Terminator and when EgorSkriptunoff pointed out this behavior from NLSSORT I just guessed the same as you (some heritage from C language). What is strange is that Oracle has left it there.

Comment: The terminating null seems to be the cause of bug 13386193, which affects export/import of a function-based index based on `nlssort`. That's fixed in 12c and 11.2.0.4, but I imagine they've worked around it in data pump rather than changing how `nlssort` works - since that would potentially cause issues with existing indexes and other code. So doesn't help, but I thought it was interesting...

Comment: New information is always welcome, so thank you @AlexPoole. I've searched for a bug in oracle to this behavior but couldn't find any. You provided a good information.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Hi there... Its been a while now. And I was seeing my post and remember this one. So I left it unanswered and as you was the first one to figure out the problem, would you add an answer of your own please? So I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'nlssort' function's documentation does not state that the output string will be a normalization of the input string,  or that they will have same length. The purpose of the function is to return data that can be used to sort the input string.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions113.htm#SQLRF51561

It is tempting to use it to normalize your string since *apparently* it works, but you are gambling here...

Heck, it could even yield a **LENGTH(b)=200** and *still* be doing what it is supposed to do :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Oracle distinguishes lengths in bytes and lengths in characters: `varchar2(55)` means 55 bytes, so 55 UTF-8 characters fit only if you are lucky: you should declare your field as `varchar2 (55 char)`.

2) Contortions like

```
replace(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(
'FGHJTÓRYO DE YHJKS DA DGHQÇÃA DE ASGA XCVBGL EASDEÔNASD', 
'nls_sort=binary_ai')),' ','_') b
```

are nonsense, you are merely replacing strings with somewhat similar ones.
Your database has an encoding, and all strings are represented with that encoding, which determines their length in bytes; the arbitrary variations mcalmeida explains introduce random data-dependent noise, never a good thing if you are making comparisons.

3) Regarding the stated task of removing accents, you should do it yourself with REPLACE, TRANSLATE etc. because only you know your requirements; it isn't Unicode normalization or anything "standard", there are no shortcuts. 
You can define a function and call it from any query and any PL/SQL program, without ugly copying and pasting.

Comment: `varchar2(55)` could also mean "55 *characters*" - it depends on the setting of `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`

Comment: If you take some time to read the comments on the question you will see that this behavior is a bug that was corrected on the version 12c and 11.2.0.4. The main problem is that the nlssort (because of the bug) left a null terminator at the end of the string (\0) after the conversion. And for `nonsense` your are totally wrong, `you are merely replacing strings with somewhat similar ones` this is exactly what I want to do. To use this cast i've studied all nls_sort equivalence characters table so before you answer to someone that things are nonsense you should understand better their problem.

Comment: Measuring the length of NLSSORT output is nonsense, and expectations on that length are dangerous nonsense. 

But fortunately you don't need to inspect lengths: if NLSSORT does exactly the transformations you need (something that I find hard to ensure given the sparsity of the documentation and the possibility of breaking changes in future Oracle updates), go ahead and use it. 

You can make NLSSORT safe by using SUBSTR to cut the result to the maximum allowed length.

Answer (score 0):

The function **"nlssort()"** return binary with extra 00 at the end of original binary of string.

Testing:

```
select NLSSORT('abc') from dual
```

Output:

> 61626300

this problem can be resolved by removing last 2 digits from NLSSORT's return.

Solution:

```
  select a, length(a), b, length(b)   
    from ( select 'FGHJTÓRYO DE YHJKS DA DGHQÇÃA DE ASGA XCVBGL EASDEÔNASD' a,
                  replace(
                      utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( 
                                 substr(nlssort('FGHJTÓRYO DE YHJKS DA DGHQÇÃA DE ASGA XCVBGL EASDEÔNASD', 'nls_sort=binary_ai'),1, 
                                                  length(nlssort('FGHJTÓRYO DE YHJKS DA DGHQÇÃA DE ASGA XCVBGL EASDEÔNASD', 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))-2 
                                                 )
                                          )

                         ,' ','_') b
             from dual
     )

  )
```