# how the utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(NLSSORT(')) works

Tags: plsql

why this query not giving any records. Please guide me

```
SELECT *
FROM DUAL 
  WHERE utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(NLSSORT('sravanth','nls_sort=binary_ai')) 
        LIKE utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(NLSSORT('sravan','nls_sort=binary_ai'))|| '%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is not working in obvious when displaying the output of `NLSSORT` :

```
SELECT NLSSORT('sravanth','nls_sort=binary_ai') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT NLSSORT('sravan','nls_sort=binary_ai') FROM DUAL
```

```
NLSSORT('SRAVANTH','NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI')
73726176616E746800
73726176616E00
            ^^
```

Please note that `NLSSORT` add an extra `NUL` char at the end of the string. This is not specified in the documentation -- and you shouldn't probably assume it will be always behave the same. Anyway, if you really want to use `NLSSORT` that way, you will have to handle the extra byte by hand. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20490866/2363712 as an example.