# Oracle - concatenating string with result of utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to concatenate a string to a result of `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2` function (which is also a string). It is supposed to be transparent, but I wasn't able to append anything to a result of `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2`.

Here is an example:

```
select  utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort('"' || CITY_NAME || ', ' || STATE_CODE || '"', 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))) || ' test' 
from (select 'New York' as CITY_NAME, 'NY' as STATE_CODE from dual)
```

I expect the result to be `"new york, ny" test` but I only get `"new york, ny"`

Comment: It may be due to a "bug" that causes the `nlssort` to add a string terminator; [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774073/strange-behavior-of-length-command-oracle) you can find something more. For example, if you try `select  dump(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort('something', 'nls_sort=binary_ai')))) from dual`, you'll see the `0` character added in the end of the string, so whatever string you add after this char, will be ignored because it comes after the end of the string.

Comment: @Aleksej - I thought it sounded familiar, but I couldn't find where I'd seen it before *8-) What's after the null isn't always completely ignored, the whole concatenated string is shown in SQL Developer for instance, but it isn't in a usable state even there really (can't copy/paste).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a combination of what may be considered a bug - but which might actually be vital to how `nlssort` is used internally by Oracle - and how your client handles strings. In SQL Developer for instance, this appears to work as expected when as a statement or as a script, but I can't copy and paste the results from the worksheet or the query result grid.

Using the `dump()` function you can see the characters that make up the result:

```
select dump(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort('"' || CITY_NAME || ', ' || STATE_CODE || '"',
  'nls_sort=binary_ai'))) || ' test', 1016) as dumped_result
from (select 'New York' as CITY_NAME, 'NY' as STATE_CODE from dual);

DUMPED_RESULT                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=20 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 22,6e,65,77,20,79,6f,72,6b,2c,20,6e,79,22,0,20,74,65,73,74
                                                                              ^
```

I've marked a `^` marker to highlight a `0` that appears in that output, between the cast `nlssort()` result and the `test` you're adding. Or a bit more clearly without the concatenation:

```
select dump(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort('ABC')), 1016) as dumped_result
from (select 'New York' as CITY_NAME, 'NY' as STATE_CODE from dual);

DUMPED_RESULT                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=4 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 41,42,43,0
```

Or even better:

```
select dump(nlssort('ABC'), 1016) as dumped_result from dual;

DUMPED_RESULT                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=23 Len=4: 41,42,43,0
```

The `nlssort()` call is adding a null byte, shown as `0` in the dump output, to the result. You client is seeing that as the end of the string, so even though Oracle is actually concatenating the strings, you just can't see the results.

You can remove the null, e.g. with `rtrim()`, before concatenating:

```
select rtrim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort('"' || CITY_NAME || ', ' || STATE_CODE || '"',
  'nls_sort=binary_ai')), chr(0)) || ' test' as result
from (select 'New York' as CITY_NAME, 'NY' as STATE_CODE from dual);

RESULT                                                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"new york, ny" test
```

or with the shorter original string:

```
select dump(rtrim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort('ABC')), chr(0)), 1016) as dumped_result
from (select 'New York' as CITY_NAME, 'NY' as STATE_CODE from dual);

DUMPED_RESULT                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=3 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 41,42,43
```

which you can see now has no trailing null character.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer. It does look like a nasty bug to me.

Comment: @AlexArt. - I'm not sure it is a bug; the behaviour isn't really documented, but the docs do refer to truncation, and the function isn't really designed for what you are doing. I suspect the null terminator is important internally.