# Trailing space is not removed after trimming

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I run this query :

```
select trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(d.det_entete, 'nls_sort=binary_ai')))) entete,
length(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(d.det_entete, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))))) nb 
from details_param_import d join param_import_table p on d.param_code = p.param_code;
```

It gave this result :

[image]

So how to remove the trailing space ?

Comment: Is there a trailing space in your result set, or does it just appear that way?

Comment: no , there is no trailing space in database .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `dump()` the modified values you can see there is a null byte at the end, rather than a space; and `length()` still counts that as a character:

```
column entete format a20
column bytes format a40

with details_param_import (det_entete) as (
  select 'nom' from dual
  union all select 'prenom' from dual
)
select trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(d.det_entete, 'nls_sort=binary_ai')))) entete,
length(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(d.det_entete, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))))) nb,
  dump(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(d.det_entete, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))))) bytes
from details_param_import d
/

ENTETE                       NB BYTES                                   
-------------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
nom                           4 Typ=1 Len=4: 110,111,109,0              
prenom                        7 Typ=1 Len=7: 112,114,101,110,111,109,0
```

which is [a side effect of how `nlssort()` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43871072/266304).

You could explicitly trim that off:

```
with details_param_import (det_entete) as (
  select 'nom' from dual
  union all select 'prenom' from dual
)
select rtrim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(d.det_entete, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))), chr(0)) entete,
length(rtrim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(d.det_entete, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))), chr(0))) nb,
  dump(rtrim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(d.det_entete, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))), chr(0))) bytes
from details_param_import d
/

ENTETE                       NB BYTES                                   
-------------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
nom                           3 Typ=1 Len=3: 110,111,109                
prenom                        6 Typ=1 Len=6: 112,114,101,110,111,109
```

Whether that is useful for whatever you are really trying to do is another matter; querying the collation key, rather than using it for ordering or comparison, probably isn't that useful. You seem to be using it to remove accents from your strings, but longer values could be truncated ([as the docs mention](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/NLSSORT.html)), and even for shorter strings it doesn't seem to guarantee you'll end up with what you expect. So, don't be too surprised if this breaks one day.

Comment: @pheromix - no, I just added that to show you what the converted value actually is, so you can see Oracle's internal representation in bytes; otherwise the null byte is invisible (though it can also stop you being able to copy-and-paste from some clients, like SQL Developer).